# Is openness crucial in Puppe's proof of the Blakers-Massey Theorem?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

Suppose a space $Y$ is given along two subspaces $Y_1,Y_2$ s.t. $Y=Y_1^{\circ}\cup Y_2^{\circ}$ and the intersection $Y_0=Y_1\cap Y_2$ is non-empty. If $(Y_1,Y_0)$ is $p$-connected and $(Y_2,Y_0)$ is $q$-connected for some $p,q\ge0$, then the inclusion induces isomorphisms $\pi_n(Y_1,Y_0,\ast)\rightarrow\pi_n(Y,Y_2,\ast)$ for $n<p+q$ and an epimorphism for $n=p+q$. This is the *Blakers-Massey Theorem*.

There are a variety of proofs of this Theorem, but the one I'm interested in the proof due to Puppe (with some inspiration by Boardman, apparently) that can be found in the book *Homotopietheorie* co-authored by tom Dieck, Kamps and Puppe himself (ch. 15) or, more recently, in tom Dieck's book [*Algebraic Topology*](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf) (Theorem 6.9.4). Notably, however, either only proves the theorem under the stronger hypothesis that the subspaces $Y_1,Y_2$ are themselves open in $Y$. The weaker version of theorem stated above is in most other places in the literature, which makes me raise the

**Question:** Is it possible to adapt the Puppe proof to the more general statement of the theorem?

Following the proof in tom Dieck, the openness appears in two places. First, in the proof of what he calls the "preparation theorem" (Theorem 6.9.2). This goes through verbatim under the weaker hypotheses. The second appearance is in the proof of the intermediate Theorem 6.9.3. It comes down to obtaining a map $\psi\colon I^n\times I\rightarrow Y$ by the preparation theorem and then modifying it by a final homotopy. This homotopy is constructed using an auxiliary function $\tau\colon I^n\rightarrow I$ which is $0$ on $\pi\psi^{-1}(Y\setminus Y_1)$ and $1$ on $\pi\psi^{-1}(Y\setminus Y_2)$, where $\pi\colon I^n\times I\rightarrow I^n$ is the projection. The previous construction ensures the two sets to be disjoint, so if $Y_1,Y_2$ are open, these sets are closed and disjoint, hence $\tau$ exists. In case of the weaker hypotheses, we would instead have to ensure that, say, $\overline{\psi^{-1}(Y\setminus Y_1)}$ and $\overline{\psi^{-1}(Y\setminus Y_2)}$ have disjoint images under $\pi$ and I have not been able to modify the constructions to obtain this.

Comment: The property that you need is that for a pushout $Y \leftarrow X \rightarrow Z$, it is a homotopy pushout. Basically just that $X \to Y$ for example is a cofibration. In your case $X$ is the intersection of two open subsets on a particularly nice space. I don't know the proofs you have in mind but it's usually a reduction to the case of a single disk in some way or another followed by smooth or simplicial approximation.

Comment: Probably you want X to admit a good open cover and the reduction is done via induction. You can take closed guys that are ANR's I assume. Really, I think one should think of Blaker's Massey in terms of inclusions of CW complexes or "excisive triads."

Comment: @AndresMejia Yes, I want the statement for excisive triads (the case of CW complexes can be deduced from the case of open triads without too much effort). I am aware of other proofs that use e.g. CW reduction techniques, but currently I am interested in this particular proof, which employs a different strategy. I've added a link to tom Dieck's book, so everybody can take a look at the proof I'm referencing.

Comment: maybe instead write a proposed proof and then I can possibly help.